# Swift change Back button title after button tap

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I have a VC that have some backbutton title "XYZ", in viewDidLoad I will change it to "ABC". Then I want to change it again with same method, but it is not working. Tried many solutions but nothing work.

I found this code. Woking in viewdidload...but after that it dont.

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(
        title: " ",
        style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
        target: nil,
        action: nil
    )
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your `UIViewController` class. This leaves the back arrow but removes the text beside it.

```
private var _title: String?
var backBarButtonHidden: Bool {
    didSet {
        if let index = navigationController?.viewControllers.indexOf(self) {
        if index > 0 {
            if let button = navigationController?.navigationBar.items?[index - 1] {
                if backBarButtonHidden {
                    _title = button.title
                   button.title = ""
                } else { button.title = _title }
            }
        }
     } 
}
```

Comment: Well this works when i am not adding my piece of code in viewdidload. But then I can't add title to the button again. :-/

Comment: Yes you can, you would have to store that title in a private variable and access the title in the exact same way:

Comment: Aha.... wow now this is what i wanted :-) thank you very much. You made me very happy :-)

Comment: Added a a variable `didSet` method to add your `UIViewController` class